# Connect from Android to SSH server without password

Tags: ssh

I want to run scripts on an Ubuntu PC from my Android phone just with a tap, no passwords or other stuff.

Things I did so far: I managed to connect via SSH to the PC, but I cannot configure a public-key authentication (I'm using CM9, for what it matters). I could create a rsa key on my phone (and stored it on the server) but it's like it's not using it when connecting, so I tried using the "ssh -i" flag but then I get an error that the string is too long. ConnectBot rsa authentication works well, but I cannot use it to run scripts. I also tried installing dropbear but I stopped as soon as I needed to compile stuff, because I could not find a complete guide, or they are mostly describing the opposite process (install an ssh server on Android). To run the scripts I use "Script Manager - SManager" that allows the creation of widgets, but so far it's always asking for the password.

Can you suggest a proper way to use pub key or any alternative solution?

Thanks!

P.S.
I know this has already been partly discussed here: [Where to add SSH keys to allow connections to remote server on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22372/where-to-add-ssh-keys-to-allow-connections-to-remote-server-on-android)
But it does not work and I cannot comment that question.

Comment: Whats the problem with ConnectBot? Have you tried "Post-login automation" option?

Comment: ConnectBot does work! But it doesn't have the functionality of SManager to create widgets that run custom scripts. So each time I would have to open the app and type in the code to run the script...

Comment: What version of ConnectBot are you using? I'm running Android 4.1.2 and ConnectBot 1.7.1 and using ConnectBot widget lets you directly establish a connection from your home screen to the desired host. If you also configure "Post-login automation" should also execute something when connected to the host.

Comment: ConnectBot 1.7.1, Android 4.0.4 and now Widget :(
But thanks for the hint!

Comment: SManager (market description and website) nowhere states it's capable of using keys, so that might be the reason. What you *could* try is something like using `sftp://user:pass@machine:port/path/to/file`. But keep in mind that this way the password is visible. And no guarantees that it works.

Comment: I am still having the same problem on CM11. Does that mean that `SSH` is broken on cyanogenmod?

Comment: Also, did you look up the error "string is too long"? Does that indicate the key or the path?

Answer (score 1):

When you provide the key (using -i switch), you should provide the path to the file, not the key itself - are you entering the file path?